# Drawing beam effect in UDK?

Tags: udk, particles

I'm having trouble drawing a particle effect between two actors in UDK - Both the source and the target are not static objects, so as far as I can tell I need to do it in the code not in kismet. Here's what I've got at the moment and it seems to not be doing anything at all. Ideas?

```
BeamEmitter[0] = new(self) class'UTParticleSystemComponent';
BeamEmitter[0].SetAbsolute(false, false, false);
BeamEmitter[0].SetTemplate(BeamTemplate[0]);

BeamEmitter[0].SetTickGroup(TG_PostUpdateWork);
BeamEmitter[0].bUpdateComponentInTick = true;
self.AttachComponent(BeamEmitter[0]);
BeamEmitter[0].SetBeamEndPoint(2, tarPos);
BeamEmitter[0].ActivateSystem();
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I get your question correctly or not but may be you will find some useful information in these 2 links of udn for showing light beams.

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/VolumetricLightingGuide.html

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/FogVolumes.html

Also you can find this article useful for "UDK Dynamic Lighting and Particle Effects"

http://www.lee-3d.com/?p=206